# forget password is send to email in android

Tags: android

I successfully developed a login form (including username,password and submit button) using a MySQL connection through soap web-services in my android application.
here I forget my password means I can't access my account.Then how to access my account.So I have added one textview(forget password???click here).I completed registration page. Registration page have username,password and email,so when I forget my password means click the forget password textview.
Then it is go to forget password activity. Here when I entered my registered email id means my password is send to my email id.So I know my password now.How can I do? Please guide me.

Do please let me know what is the steps are follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this procedure.

1. Let the email registered be Unique for all the Users
2. Now keep the forgot UserName And Password Button on the login Screen.
3. When the user clicks this button,Ask him for his email address Only
4. Go On to check this email Address,If the email Address is found,then send the username and password(reset on) to that email address
5. Or else Toast a message that this email address is not registered.